# Using Composition to Prove Inverse Functions

Tags: functions, inverse-function

I am asked to prove whether two functions are inverses of each other using composition.

The functions given are
$$f(x)=\dfrac 1{(x-3)}$$
$$ g(x)=\dfrac {(3x+1)}x$$

I've solved the first function (*f*(*x*)), and gotten *x* as the answer (meaning, it is the inverse). However, I'm struggling on solving for the second inverse function. I've shown my work below, of which I'm *fairly* sure is error-free, but what I'm stuck on is attempting to solve to have '*x*' as the answer to *g*(*f*(*x*))=4/(*x*²+3*x*). I know that it is the inverse (or, should be), since I checked last night and I believe I found it was. However, I couldn't find the steps to do so anywhere.

Work:

*g*(*x*)=(3*x*+1)/x

*g*(*f*(*x*))=(3(1/(*x*-3)+1)/*x*

*g*(*f*(*x*))=(3·(1/(*x*-3))+1)/*x* -- *a*(*bc*)=*a*·*bc*

*g*(*f*(*x*))=(((3·1)/(*x*-3))+1)/*x* -- *a*·(*b*/*c*)=(*a*·*b*)/*c*

*g*(*f*(*x*))=(((3·1)/(*x*-3))+(1(*x*-3))/(*x*-3))/*x* -- *a*=(*a*(*b*))/*b*

*g*(*f*(*x*))=((3+1)/(*x*-3))/*x*

*g*(*f*(*x*))=(((3+1)/(*x*-3))/*x*)/1 -- *a*/*b*/*c*=*a*/*b*/*c*/1

*g*(*f*(*x*))=((3+1)/(*x*-3))*(1/*x*) -- *a*/*b*/*c*/*d*=(*a*/*b*)*(*d*/*c*)

*g*(*f*(*x*))=((3(1/*x*)+(1/*x*))/-3(1/*x*)

*g*(*f*(*x*))=((4(1/*x*))/-3(1/*x*)

Aaaand I'm stuck there.

Comment: Check again the first step, where you make the substitution. I.e. going from $g(x)$ to $g(f(x))$.

Comment: @DanielDiaz Welcome to Math SE. As posilon's comment states, the issue is with going from $g(x)$ to $g(f(x))$. Note you must substitute $f(x)$ for *all* occurrences of $x$ in $g(x)$ to get $g(f(x))$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thank you. I had assumed something was wrong with my math in the latter steps, and hadn't considered that I had simply overlooked the second occurrence of _x_ in the first step. Thank you for the assistance.